# I want to log my data using getInitialProps() from next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to next.js and react, I just want to get back the data from this free api https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

index.js component

```
import UserList from "./userList";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <UserList></UserList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

UserList component:

```
const UserList = (data) => {
console.log(data);
return <div>test</div>;
};
UserList.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`);
  const data = await resp.json();
  console.log(data);
  return { data };
};
export default UserList;
```

using `console.log(data)` doesn't do anything, any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function UserList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
  async function getUsers() {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return <>{loading ? <div>...Data Loading.....</div> : <div>{<p> {data.page}</p>}</div>}</>;
}

export default UserList;
```